# How do I create new measure filtered by a dimension?

Tags: tableau-api

Hello Currently I have a measure of Student count, I also have dimension of Student Year(Year 1, Year 2, Year 3, Year 4) and School(School 1, School 2, School 3). I am trying to visualize the percentage of Year 1 Student with respect to Student count in each school. That is why I am trying to make a new measure of student count filtered by Student Year(Year 1).

So far I ended with percentage but with respect to total student count, not student count for each school. Tried a few stuff with calculated field, but I am not sure how I apply "Student count" only if "Student Year" = "Year 1"

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be solveable with a [Level-of-Detail-Expression](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.htm). I think it should look something like this:

Step 1: Create a calculated field [first year student count] only representing the number of Year 1 Students

```
IF [year]='Year 1' THEN [student count] END
```

Step 2: Create a second calculated field where the Level-of-Detail of [first year student count] is fixed to school.

```
SUM({FIXED [school]: SUM([first year student count])})/SUM([student count])
```